# Spring Boot Cannot Find EmbeddedKafkaBroker Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am writing an integration tests for Kafka. For that, I am using Spring's `EmbeddedKafka`. Here's my class:

```
@Component
@EmbeddedKafka(
    partitions = 1,
    topics = {"Topic},
    brokerProperties = {"listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9091", "port=9091"})
public class KafkaConsumerTestUtils {
  @Autowired private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka;
  ....
}
```

I am autowiring this utils class in my classes annotated with `@SpringBootTest`. Here's the error I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1646)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1205)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 66 more
```

The weird thing is, when I autowire `EmbeddedKafkaBroker` in any of my test classes, it is created and the tests run fine.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly sure why, but looks like you are not using it the way it was intended to be used.

@EmbeddedKafka is an annotation that can be specified on a test class that runs Spring Kafka based tests.

Documentation states:

```
The typical usage of this annotation is like:
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @EmbeddedKafka
 public class MyKafkaTests {}
```

Comment: Actually that was the problem. I fixed with by adding a @SpringBootTest to my utils class. Thanks.